# Java, error when using @Override for method with different parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, overriding, mouselistener

I am trying to call the method `doMouse` when I click the mouse this is what I came up with. I have tried `ge.addMouseListener` but IntelliJ does not like that at all. I currently have an error with `UI.MouseListener cannot apply java.awt.event.MouseAdapter`. If anyone can explain why is this and how can I get this to work I would appreciate it.

```
import ecs100;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GUIExercise{

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        GUIExercise  ge = new GUIExercise();
        UI.setMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override // error here fixed
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                doMouse( "", e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });

        UI.println("Select a .JPG file from the Choose file button.");
        UI.println("Click the mouse in the graphics pane to paste the image");
    }
}
```

Comment: `//error here` what error?

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to override a method that doesn't exist, and thus the annotation is working properly (and helped prevent a more difficult to debug runtime problem). You wanted [`MouseAdapter.mouseClicked(MouseEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    doMouse("", e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```

Comment: Thanks the @override is now working, but as i suspected Mouse Adapter does not work with the UI Mouse Listener. is it possible to see why i cant replace UI.setMouseListener with ge.addMouseListener which will work with java.awt.event.MouseAdapter ?

Comment: @Diggy I haven't seen `UI`, in what way does it "not work"?

Comment: It provides this error. 'setMouseListener (ecs100.UIMouseListener) in UI cannot be applied to (anonymous java.awt.event.MouseAdapter) As far as i can tell im required to use ge.addMouseListener'. but when using this it provides this error 'Can not resolve method addMouseListener'

Comment: Because `ge` is an instance of your posted class `GUIExercise`; it doesn't implement MouseListener (or have any instance methods, or do anything really).

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. I may have it figured out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't say without seeing `UI`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `override` the behaviour of base class in its sub class.

Any new method added in the sub class is not a behaviour of base class and hence adding `override` annotation will give you a compile time error.

In your case you have an anonymous subclass of the `MouseAdapter`. The name and signature of the method (for mouse click) is

`public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`

You have in your case `mouseClick` (ed is missing in the name, so its like you have added a separate new method in your subclass). Hence your IDE tells you the same by giving you the compile time error when you add `override` annotation to your another separate new method.